# Show that the space $X$ is not a surface

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, quotient-spaces

I would like to show that the following space is not a surface:

$X$ is made as an identification space of the unit square $Q=\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq x,y\leq1\}$ with the identifications:

$(0,y)\sim(1,y)$ for all $0\leq y \leq1$

$(x,0)\sim(x+\frac{1}{2},0)$ for all $0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$

$(x,1)\sim(x+\frac{1}{2},1)$ for all $0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$

In particular, I would like to find a point on the space which has a neighbourhood that is non-locally Euclidean.

I have so far managed to convince myself that the space cannot be a surface. This is because if we first consider the unit square with the first identification, we get a cylinder, and the second identification then implies that the top-left point of the unit square, as well as the top-centre point both get identified to the top-right point. Likewise, every point between the top-left point and the top-centre point gets identified to a point between the top-centre point and the top-right point. This produces some "overlap". Of course the same applies for the points at the bottom of the square by symmetry.

My difficulty lies in taking, say, the top-centre point, which gets identified to both the top-left and top-right points, and finding a neighborhood about it that is non-locally Euclidean.

I am afraid that my abilities are not quite adequate for me to be able to provide diagrams, but I hope I have made myself understandable verbally.

Note: By surface I mean a compact, connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is locally homeomorphic to open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Any help or input would, as always, be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is a surface in the usual sense but it does not embed in $R^3$ (it is the Klein bottle), hence, it will violate your definition. The standard definition of a surface is 2nd countable Hausdorff topological space locally homeomorphic to $R^2$.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093368/topological-space-formed-by-the-identification-of-a-unit-square).