# Topological space formed by the identification of a unit square

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, triangulation

[image]

I know that the first identification "rolls up" the unit square to form a cylinder with open ends but I'm unsure on how the next two "close up" the ends. Does it become a cylinder or more of a cone ending? Also I'm really bad at triangulating surfaces so any help with that would be very useful.

Comment: On each circle of the cylinder, the antipodal points get identified, or equivalently you rotate by 180 degrees. This identification doesn't happen nicely in 3-dimensional space.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092781/show-that-the-space-x-is-not-a-surface).